# Ubuntu 15.10: blurry texts and images

Tags: graphics, display, 15.10, intel-graphics, fonts

I'm all new to Linux systems environment, therefore as Ubuntu itself — I'm using the 15.10 "*Wily Werewolf*" version —, and I've already searched a lot on the internet, in this, and several other forums, for answers to this particular issue, and none of them were helpful, or were just specific for some graphic cards, and always non-generic answers. What I'm looking for is an all-cases solution, independing on the user's graphic card, if possible. That would be more helpful not just for me, but also for other users who may are experiencing the same issue, I think.

The problem consists in a blur in the texts and images inside Ubuntu folders and directories and internet browsers, in all folders and files names, websites addresses, PHP and HTML sites texts in general, it looks like the fonts are **corrupted**, or something like that. Sometimes constant and very intense, like a pixelation effect, that distorts the words and doesn't allow me to see/read absolutely nothing, and sometimes it's less strong, and just appear when I pass the mouse cursor through a specific text or image, then it becomes slightly blurry. I'm not very sure about this, but I noticed that the blur effect sometimes becomes stronger when the CPU and memory is in high usage, when I have multiple things open up, for example.

*Here's an image with the blur effect (slighter, at this time) in some textboxes inside Ubuntu keyboard settings:*
[image]

In advance, two notes: ¹yes, I've already updated my graphic card's drivers, directly downloading the latest version for it right on the manufacturer's official website, and ²yes, I've checked the ideal resolution for my screen, it's 1920 x 1080 pixels, 16:9 aspect ratio (I'm using a LG Flatron E2240, if useful).

Do anyone know a fix for this issue?

My PC hardware basic details and configuration, according directly to Ubuntu "System Setting > All Settings > Details":

- Processor: Intel® Core™2 CPU 6300 @ 1.86GHz × 2
- Graphics: Intel® G33
- Memory: 2,9 GiB
- OS type: 64-bit
- Disk: 26,3 GB

> *Not a very good or fast PC, I know, but that's all I have, ha ha.*

If some additional info is required to help me find a solution for this issue, just reply to this question and I'll find it out and then put it here as fast as possible.

I'm Brazilian, therefore a portuguese native speaker, so I'm sorry for any grammatical mistakes on my part.

I really don't know more what to do. Always wanted to migrate to a Linux system distribution, and everyone adviced me to star with Ubuntu, but I just can't continue trying it with this problem, being a visual and thus a very disturbing one.

Comment: Yikes I would call that a "corruption" not a "blur"! And it's only on some text, other text looks great.  I would assume it's the particular font missing but I can't wait to see the answers come in, interesting question. And by the way, except for maybe mixing up blur and corruption, your English is pretty impressive!

Comment: Thanks for both the advice and compliment, JimLohse! I'll edit the post and add the corruption term, hope it helps to make myself more understandable.
However, I'm afraid that the problem may are not related to missing or corrupted fonts, because it's affecting not just texts lines, but images, and recently I've noticed some icons in the Desktop and Launcher being affected by the blur too, as well as videos played inside Chrome and Firefox browsers (the only ones I've tested).

Comment: But anyway I'll search for some "missing and corrupted fonts" topics around Ubuntu forums and try to figure out if that's the problem, if so, I tag the post as solved.

Let's keep waiting for more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Are all of these packages installed?

```
fonts-dejavu-core
fonts-khmeros-core
ttf-ancient-fonts-symbola
ttf-dejavu-core
ttf-indic-fonts-core
ttf-ubuntu-font-family
```

I got that list by running:

```
$ strace -o unity-control-center.strace -s 8192 -f unity-control-center
$ grep open\( unity-control-center.strace  | grep ttf | sed -e 's;^.*(";;' -e 's;".*$;;' | xargs dpkg -S | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort -u
```

Also I switched to the keyboard panel in the unity-control-center (which the GUI calls System Settings).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Metta Crawler! I've already checked these fonts, and they're all installed and working normally.

I guess that the problem is most probably caused due to a graphic issue than something related to the fonts itself, because I've checked all of them, and none was missing or corrupted. I followed instructions and checking protocols given me by members of this same forum in other topics, and as far as I see they worked well.

Comment: Don't know how to or if that's possible at all, but later I intend on trying to reinstall all my fonts. If it comes to solve my problem I tag the post as solved with your answer.

Comment: Have you looked at fonts using `gnome-font-viewer`? You can type "font viewer" into the Dash (upper left button that opens a text field).

Comment: It is interesting that some fonts do work.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same effect after the latest update on Ubuntu 15.10 yesterday. It feels like some weird Compiz plugin has been enabled, but I can see nothing in Compiz. The text is blurry by default, but passing a mouse over it brings it into focus. But not all areas come into focus. Images also seem affected. My computer has Nvidia card, and I updated to the newest available open source Nvidia driver, and that seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In the 'system settings' go to 'Appearance'. Under 'Theme' either keep 'Ambiance' or 'High Contrast' (for even better bold text). 'Radiance' option seems to be blurry in general.
Hope this helps.